# Need a file upload using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file-upload, client-side

```
<input type="file" id="fileToUpload" />
<input type="button" id="btnFup" value="Upload" onclick="fileUpload();" />
```

I want to upload an image to the server side folder using JavaScript or jQuery only. I don't want to use the code behind. Any Suggestions?

Comment: You need server-side code to accept the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- [JavaScript: Upload file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5587973/javascript-upload-file)
- http://www.google.pl/search?q=javascript+file+upload&sugexp=chrome,mod=16&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8
- http://www.queness.com/post/11434/7-javascript-ajax-file-upload-plugins
- http://igstan.ro/posts/2009-01-11-ajax-file-upload-with-pure-javascript.html

?

Comment: None of those address the "I dont want to use code behind." part of the question. Lists of links are much better placed as comments then answers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to use something serverside.  This is one of the best things to use for file upload http://www.uploadify.com/