# how can i convert image file size to a smaller size

Tags: php

i wanted to know what's the best way to make my 3mb photo smaller on upload i have this upload form but for some reason it wont upload images over 2mb i keep getting "file is too small or large" PHP ONLY

```
$valid_exts = array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'gif');
$max_file_size = 2000000 * 1234567; 
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    if ( isset($_FILES['image']) ) {
        if (! $_FILES['image']['error'] && $_FILES['image']['size'] < $max_file_size) {
            $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($_FILES['image']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
            if (in_array($ext, $valid_exts)) {
                    if (!file_exists('photos/' )) {
                        mkdir('photos/' , 0777, true);
                        }
                    $path = 'photos/' . uniqid() . '.' . $ext;
                    $size = getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);


                    $x = (int) $_POST['x'];
                    $y = (int) $_POST['y'];
                    $w = (int) $_POST['w'] ? $_POST['w'] : $size[0];
                    $h = (int) $_POST['h'] ? $_POST['h'] : $size[1];

                    $data = file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
                    $vImg = imagecreatefromstring($data);
                    $dstImg = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);
                    imagecopyresampled($dstImg, $vImg, 0, 0, $x, $y, $w, $h, $w, $h);
                    imagejpeg($dstImg, $path);
                    imagedestroy($dstImg);
                    /*print_r($path);*/



                } else {
                    echo 'unknown problem!';
                } 
        } else {
            echo 'file is too small or large';
        }
    } else {
        echo 'file not set';
    }
} else {
    echo 'bad request!';
}
```

Comment: I'm just curious, but... in this part: `$max_file_size = 2000000 * 1234567;` what are those numbers doing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to compress an image via Javascript in the browser?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14672746/how-to-compress-an-image-via-javascript-in-the-browser)

Comment: How's the php.ini look? What's the maximum file size you're allowed there? If that's set to 2MB max, that may be your limit there, not anything with your script directly.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184513/php-change-the-maximum-upload-file-size

Comment: its supposed to be the bytes, that would add up to the total bytes

Comment: no not a duplicate im asking php only not javascript

Comment: max files size is 10M

Comment: 2,000,000 * 1,234,567 = 2.47e+12, roughly. That's a mighty big image file. I'd have thought 10000000 would be big enough.

Comment: `$max_file_size = 2000000 * 1234567;` So your max file size is 2.2TB? 1MB is `1024*1024` or `1,048,576`, BTW.

Comment: well i wanted to have $max_file_size be big enough just in case the file size is bigger than expected.

Comment: well stop talking about max_file_size if its not going to solve the problem, please

Comment: @Sammitch That could also be written as `1024^2`

Comment: @user2865738: You can't in php if you can't upload over 2mb. it _has_ to be done client-side otherwise you're going to continue to battle a server-side threshold.

Comment: @Kermit not in php! `^` is one of the bitwise operators. Forget which, though. `pow(1024,2)` or `pow(2,20)`. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$_FILES['image']['error']` is an *integer* code where `UPLOAD_ERR_OK` is `0`. [Docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php)

Replace:

```
if (! $_FILES['image']['error'] && $_FILES['image']['size'] < $max_file_size)
```

With:

```
if ( ($_FILES['image']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) && ($_FILES['image']['size'] < $max_file_size) )
```

and I would suggest not even bothering to check the size of the file if you don't care how large the file may be. There's no point in arbitrarily setting an impossible max file size like that when you're already constrained by:

1. `post_max_size` and `upload_max_size` in `php.ini`.
2. Potentially the post size constriants of your HTTP server/CGI gateway. [IIS springs to mind]
3. The 2GB upload limit imposed by shortcomings in PHP's core. [file size is tracked in a signed 32bit integer regardless of your architecture.