# Image compress and resize when uploading

Tags: symfony, file-upload, image-compression

I am building an application with symfony which requires images upload. The images are of high definition and large size which take long to upload. Please is there any where i that the image can be compressed and resized as there are uploaded to the server? Thank you for your time

Comment: As they are uploaded... not so much. But after they are uploaded, yes. You're looking for an extension for symphony which manages images. image.intervention. GD Library and Imagick

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do that before uploading the image, it has nothing to do with symfony, as it will have to be done on the client side, probably with Javascript.

A good starting point could be this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14672943/2507740

Comment: Thanks alot for the answer. That was a good read. Also found a very good video explaining and demonstrating how it can be achieved https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W1hoGEBccOA