# Blob after canvas.toBlob is too heavy

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, frontend, blob

We use S3 storage for hosting our photos. There is a feature on our client that allows to put some masks on the image and send it to S3 to update it.

The problem is that when you initially download a photo it weights about 300kb, but when you do canvas.toBlob and send it on the S3 it weights about 1.5mb. How can I cope with this problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14672746/how-to-compress-an-image-via-javascript-in-the-browser?

Comment: @Andy okay, will talk to our backend developers. The problem is I do not know whether s3 allows to decode dataURL or we will have to make a middleware for this

Comment: @Andy the other problem is that there are some "resize" actions, but it seems that we can save the file lossless just changing the encoding

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't set the file type when converting your canvas

try this

```
YOUR_CANVAS.toBlob(function (blob) {
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('img', blob, YOUR_FILE_NAME);
        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function () {
                alert('uploaded');
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('error')
            },
        });
    },YOUR_FILE_TYPE);
```

`YOUR_FILE_TYPE` can be "image/jpg" or "image/png" or ...

[canvas to blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob#examples)