# How to stop page reload when RadioButtonList clicked without using UpdatePanel?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015, updatepanel, radiobuttonlist

I am using a RadioButtonList in my web page where RadioButtonList items are A and B. When Item B clicked I am showing few ImageBoxes with FileUploadControl and adding them to database. When I click the radio button values my page gets refreshed. I have tried using the UpdatePanel and then it worked fine without the page refresh but I was not able to add the values to the database. I've got a null exception where the FileName became empty even after selecting the image from the FileUploadControl

I have searched regarding this and [found](https://www.aspforums.net/Threads/213604/ASPNet-FileUpload-PostedFile-gives-NULL-Reference-Exception/) that the selected file will be lost if the FileUploadControl is added inside the UpdatePanel.

below given code segment is how I get the image name

```
string imageFile = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
```

Is there any other way to achieve both? (adding them to DB and click without page refresh)

EDITED WITH FULL CODE:

```
  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                <Triggers>
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="RadioButtonList1" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
                    <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" />
                </Triggers>
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <div class="textAnswers" id="textAns" runat="server">
                        <p>
                            <b>A.</b>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="answerOneTb" runat="server" Width="95%"></asp:TextBox>
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <b>B.</b>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="answerTwoTb" runat="server" Width="95%"></asp:TextBox>
                        </p>

                    </div>
                    <div class="imageAnswers" id="imageAns" runat="server">
                        <div id="imageA">
                            <b>A.</b>
                            <asp:Image ID="Image1" CssClass="images" runat="server" ImageUrl="..\Folder\blankImage.png" Width="150px" />
                            &nbsp;

                        </div>
                        <div id="imageB">
                            <b>B.</b>
                            <asp:Image ID="Image2" CssClass="images" runat="server" ImageUrl="..\Folder\blankImage.png" Width="150px" />
                            &nbsp;

                        </div>                                                        
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <br />

                    </div>

                    <div class="fileUpload" id="addImageFupld" runat="server">
                        <div id="fu1">
                            <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" Width="150px" onchange="ImagePreviewA(this)" accept=".png,.jpg,.jpeg" /><br />
                            <br />
                            <dx:ASPxLabel ID="imageName1" runat="server" Text="ASPxLabel" Visible="false"></dx:ASPxLabel>
                        </div>

                        <div id="fu2">
                            <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload2" runat="server" Width="150px" onchange="ImagePreviewB(this)" accept=".png,.jpg,.jpeg" /><br />
                            <dx:ASPxLabel ID="imageName2" runat="server" Text="ASPxLabel" Visible="false"></dx:ASPxLabel>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Add Question" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

In the above given code segment **textAnswers** (Div tag) will be hidden while the user selects Item A in the RadioButtonList and When he clicks Item B **imageAnswers** and **fileUpload** will be visible. While clicking these to Items in the RadioButtonList Page gets refreshed and the values are added to the DB. But I need to stop the page reload and add the values to the DB at the same time. When I use Update Panel I am getting FileName becomes null and getting a null exception in my Code Behind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically your update panel need to make full postback when you upload a file. For that you need to you Post back trigger in update panel.

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updPanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="RadioButtonList1" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnUpload" />
    </Triggers>
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:FileUpload ID="fupload" runat="server" /><br />
                <asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" Text="Upload"  />
   <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
                        <asp:ListItem Text="T1" Value="M1"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="T2" Value="M2"></asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:RadioButtonList>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Also make sure that you have this.Form.Enctype = "multipart/form-data"; set in your code, or you can put in that page.

Alternatively you need to use Jquery/Javascript to achieve the RadiobuttonList click event.

Comment: Let me know if it works or you faces any issues with it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried it. It did't work. Can you explain me the reason of using  <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" />

Comment: Post back trigger makes the full post back for the page instead of partial post back from the update panel

Comment: I have made minor change in my answer I added ID of the file upload control in the PostBackTrigger, try that I think it should work.

Comment: I am getting this error.
"Control with ID 'FileUpload1' being registered through RegisterAsyncPostBackControl or RegisterPostBackControl must implement either INamingContainer, IPostBackDataHandler, or IPostBackEventHandler."

Comment: @coder I have updated my answer you can use that now.

Comment: I want to stop the page refresh while clicking the RadioButtonList. Not while clicking the upload button.

Comment: Yes using update panel you will stop the page refresh while clicking the RadioButtonList but when you will select a file using file upload and click upload button it will refresh the page to post the file on the server. I think this was your requrirement.

Comment: yeah. Thats my requirement. By using your code when I click RadioButtonList, it refreshes the page. Is it because that I am not using this.Form.Enctype = "multipart/form-data"; ??
if so where should I put that?

Comment: No you need to put your RadioButtonList inside update panel.

Comment: Can you please share your code? what is the problem you are facing now?

Comment: I have edited my question with my full code. Kindly let me know where the issue is.

Comment: @Coder, I can not see RadioButtonList inside the UpdatePanel I think you have not added that inside it. Please move it inside the panel and then check.

Comment: ok I think setting AutoPostBack=true is doing the magic. I have updated my answer please check and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Well this may not sound good but if clicking on radio button was making postback you can turn AutoPostBack="false" and capture that onchange event in clientside using jquery and displayed those imageboxes and fileupload control and then you don't need to use updatepanel and everything will work fine.

Comment: Hi. thanks for the answer. it did not work that is why i used the update panel

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to don't use update panel, instead use ajax in jquery for partial update (asyncronous communication.)

Here you can find how can you upload file using jQuery
[How to upload file using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29910490/how-to-upload-file-using-javascript)

Here you can find how can you toggle (show/ hide) controls on click of radio button. 
[Show hide controls on radio button click.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5940963/show-and-hide-divs-based-on-radio-button-click)

Hope this might help you.

Comment: HI. Thanks for the answer. I will check and let you know :)