# try..catch not catching async/await errors

Tags: javascript, async-await, try-catch, fetch-api

Perhaps I misunderstood how catching errors with `async/await` is supposed to work from things articles like this https://jakearchibald.com/2014/es7-async-functions/ and this http://pouchdb.com/2015/03/05/taming-the-async-beast-with-es7.html, but my `catch` block is not catching 400/500.

```
async () => {
  let response
  try {
   let response = await fetch('not-a-real-url')
  }
  catch (err) {
    // not jumping in here.
    console.log(err)
  }
}()
```

[example on codepen if it helps](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JYLwEW?editors=001)

Comment: AFAK the fetch api dont considter 400/500 errors

Answer (score 94, accepted):

400/500 is not an error, it's a response. You'd only get an exception (rejection) when there's a network problem.

When the server answers, you have to check whether it's [good](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-response-ok) or not:

```
try {
    let response = await fetch('not-a-real-url')
    if (!response.ok) // or check for response.status
        throw new Error(response.statusText);
    let body = await response.text(); // or .json() or whatever
    // process body
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
}
```