# NextJS - Can you use a return from an api in a conditional?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a change password function that hits this api for verification and I want to display an error if the current password is incorrect.

Any direction on how to go about this or if what I'm doing makes no sense please point me in the right direction if would be so kind, it would be greatly appreciated!

```js
case "PUT":
      try {
        const validContact = await Contact.findOne({ _id: req.body.id });

        const valid = bcrypt.compareSync(
          req.body.currentPassword,
          validContact.password
        );

        if (valid) {
          const hashedPassword = bcrypt.hashSync(
            req.body.newPassword,
            bcrypt.genSaltSync()
          );
          const contact = await Contact.findOneAndUpdate(
            { _id: req.body.id },
            { password: hashedPassword },
            { new: true }
          );

          res.status(200).json({ success: true, data: contact });
        }
        res.status(400).json({ success: false });
      } catch (error) {
        res.status(400).json({ success: false });
      }
      break;
```

This is the function that calls the API upon form submission

```js
const submitNewPassword = (submitNewPasswordForm, resetForm) => {
    submitNewPasswordForm(); // <-- I want to put this in a conditional
    resetForm();
    setOpenPasswordPopup(false);
    setNotify({
      isOpen: true,
      message: "Password updated successfully",
      type: "success",
    });
  };
```

edit: submitNewPassword function

```js
const submitNewPasswordForm = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await fetch(`${process.env.APP_DOMAIN}/api/${apiRoute}`, {
        method: "PUT",
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json",
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(values),
      });
      router.push(`${process.env.APP_DOMAIN}/`);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

Comment: Can you post the code for `submitNewPasswordForm()`? Does that function return anything you can check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `submitNewPasswordForm` doesn't return anything right now (well, it does, but it's just an empty Promise). To be able to check if it was a good request or not, you need to return something from it. Example:

```
const submitNewPasswordForm = async () => {
  try {
    const res = await fetch(`${process.env.APP_DOMAIN}/api/${apiRoute}`, {
      method: "PUT",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(values),
    });

    // this check is also necessary; 400 isn't an exception that would get caught
    if (!res.ok) {
      throw new Error(res.statusText)
    }
    router.push(`${process.env.APP_DOMAIN}/`);
    return true;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    // you could also re-throw the error, or return something else
    return false;
  }
};
```

Because it's an async function, it returns a Promise, so you need to get the return value out with a `.then`:

```
const submitNewPassword = (submitNewPasswordForm, resetForm) => {
  submitNewPasswordForm()
    .then((ok) => {
      if (!ok) {
        // show error
      } else {
        resetForm();
        setOpenPasswordPopup(false);
        setNotify({
          isOpen: true,
          message: "Password updated successfully",
          type: "success",
        });
      }
    })
};
```

If you re-throw the error in the first function, you could `.catch` it rather than checking for an `ok` value. You could also make the second function an `async` function if you wanted to. Example:

```
const submitNewPassword = async (submitNewPasswordForm, resetForm) => {
  try {
    submitNewPasswordForm()
    // rest of the code
  } catch (err) {
    // show error
  }
}
```

Whichever way you go, you'll have to return something from the function in order to know if it was a success or not.

Comment: Was that request with the same data coming back with a 200 before the change?

Comment: Oh, I missed that issue — a 400 response is still an okay response, it needs to be handled as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33355142/5774952)

Comment: I also updated my answer with that change.

Comment: Does the network tab of the devtools show that the the response was a 400 still?

Comment: Cool, problem isolated! It must be an issue with that endpoint. If you have trouble with that, that should go in a new question though.

Comment: Ohhh that's my bad i was playing around with the api and forgot to put the status(400) back. Now I'm getting the error shown in my edit above in the console and the try statement is still running when an incorrect password entered.

Comment: got this to work! It doesn't like the async function, when I tried with the `.then` everything worked as expected. Thank you so much for the help Zac!

Answer (score -1):

You will need to declare the submitNewPassword with async as you will require to await.

Then I added the await before the submitNewPasswordForm() and the happy and unhappy path.

You can check the result here.

```
const submitNewPassword = async (submitNewPasswordForm, resetForm) => {

  const response = await submitNewPasswordForm(); // <-- I want to put this in a conditional
  if(response.status === 200){
    const body = await response.json()
    //happy path
  }else
  {
    const bodyError = await response.json()
    //unhappy path 
  }
  resetForm();
  setOpenPasswordPopup(false);
  setNotify({
    isOpen: true,
    message: "Password updated successfully",
    type: "success",
  });
};
```

Comment: When running this I get an error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined` which points to the `if (response.status === 200)`

Comment: Can you post your code? If submitNewPasswordForm is an async function, then it is impossible that it will return undefined.