# upload an image in javascript to alfresco api

Tags: javascript, alfresco

I'm working on a application that has to upload an image to alfresco.I already looked to the documentation (http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/references/RESTful-UploadUploadPost.html) but I find this really unclear. I'm new at Alfresco. Does anyone has an example to do this in javascript ?

Thanks

Comment: What version of Alfresco are you using? Alfresco 5.1 adds a number of very nice and easy to use (+well documented!) public APIs

Comment: Also, how are you creating your application - are you basing this on the existing Share client? Are you using one of the Maven Archetypes to build a new archetype running on Surf?

Comment: Are you having trouble for using alfresco API or uploading a file in JS ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5587973/javascript-upload-file

Comment: @Gagravarr Thanks for your answer, I'm using the Alfresco 5.1 Community edition. But I don't find a clear documentation to upload an image file (properties as form-url-encode or POST,..).

Comment: @DaveDraper I am programming an application in Appcelerator (javascript) but the Appcelerator SDK only can upload textfiles.