# file upload : fetch file from a specific web directory

Tags: html

I am trying to use the file upload option in html

```
<form action="/action_page.php">
  <input type="file" name="pic" accept=".doc">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

I understand that the browsers will not allow absolute path due to security reasons. What I am looking for is, for a user to use a web-resource directory like dropbox to retrive and store (modified via the application) files.

Currently, the file upload is local (to-user) which disallows

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5587973/javascript-upload-file

Comment: I did go through this. Its not exactly helpful