# uploading file with <form> doesn't sends the file

Tags: html, forms, upload

I am trying to upload file based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5587986/11253551):

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="http://localhost:61113/api/file/upload" method="post">
   <div>
          <input type="text" placeholder="No file selected" id="txtPath" />
          <div id="div-btn">
             Choose File
             <input type="file" class="hide_file" id="browse-btn">
           </div>
    </div>
    <button id="btnScan" type="submit">Scan</button>
</form>
```

but in the server side I only get at the content of the request:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryYhhj0sW5ARh7d9ZO--
```

and I cant see the file's content, I meen it seems like it doesn't sends the file, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to insert also the attribute `name` for the input file.

Than get the file data through [`$_FILES`](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/reserved.variables.files.php); the value of the `name` attribute will be a key in the `$_FILES` array.

For example:

```
<input type="file" class="hide_file" id="browse-btn" name='fileUploaded'>
```

in the server side:

```
$fileData = $_FILES['fileUploaded'];
```

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the name attribute

```
<input type="file" class="hide_file" id="browse-btn" name="file">
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all are you using AJAX? If so, there is no need for `name` attribute. You can get file with `id` attribute, but if not so you must use `name` attribute.