# Trouble with sending .zip file on server with fetch()

Tags: javascript, php

I try to send my .zip file on server, this way:

```
function sendData(){
    let zipFile = document.getElementById('fileReciever').files[0];
    let formData = new FormData();

    formData.append('id', btoa('7804044924'));
    formData.append('data', zipFile);
    fetch('http://localhost/xmlReader/reciever.php', {method: "POST", body: formData});
}
```

but on server (php) in $_POST i getting only "id" field, "data" is absent. What i am doing wrong?

i try this way:

```
let zipFile = document.getElementById('fileReciever').files[0];
let formData = new FormData();

formData.append('id', btoa('7804044924'));
formData.append('data', zipFile);
//fetch('http://localhost/xmlReader/reciever.php', {method: "POST", body: formData});

let req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("POST", 'http://localhost/xmlReader/reciever.php');
req.send(formData);
```

but result is same - on server in $_POST i getting only one field - "id", field "data" is absent.

Comment: Anyone can help me? I do exactly the way in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5587973/javascript-upload-file, but get hothing in field "data" on server side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to catch the files you have to use $_FILES instead of $_POST.

Let's say you sent an image than you var_dump($_FILES), you will get an array content

- [Name]: the name (comes from the browser, so treat as tainted)
- [type] => image/jpeg (type of the file)
- [tmp_name] => /tmp/php/php1h4j1o (depending on your config settings, but the user has no control, so this isn't tainted)
- [error] => UPLOAD_ERR_OK  (= 0)
- [size] => 123 (the size in bytes)

and so you get your file-data.

[Here](https://www.php.net/manual/de/reserved.variables.files.php) you find good examples like the one i used here.