# Uploading file backend express and frontend react using multer missing stream property

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, path, multer

I'm trying to successfully upload a file (image) but something goes wrong because the file appears to get moved to the correct directory but it's of size 0 as if it doesn't actually have any content and when I try to open it.. it fails. I think I might be missing "stream" because when i console.log the file on the backend there is no stream property.. and I also get an error in the console saying "The "source" argument must be of type function or an instance of Stream, Iterable, or AsyncIterable. Received undefined"

My front end:

```
const UploadPoster = ({books_id}) => {
  const [file, setFile] = useState();
  
  const send = () => {
    const data = new FormData();
    data.append('file', file);

    Axios.post(`${HOST}/books/${books_id}/upload`, data, {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`
      },
    })
    .then(res => console.log(res))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
    
    history.go(0)
  };

  const history = useHistory();
  
  return (
    <>
      <form action="#">
        <div className="flex">
        <label htmlFor="file">Update book cover:</label>
        <input type="file" id="file" onChange={event => {
          const file = event.target.files[0];
          setFile(file);
        }} />
      </div>
    </form>
    <Button onClick={send}>Upload</Button>
    </>
  )
}
```

My backend:

```
    .post('/:id/upload', authMiddleware, loggedUserGuard, roleMiddleware(userRole.Admin), upload.single('file'), async (req, res) => {
      const {file} = req;

      await pipeline(
          file.stream,
          fs.createWriteStream(`${__dirname}/../../../front_end/public/posters/${req.file.originalname}`),
      );

      res.send('File uploaded as ' + req.file.originalname);
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to append your Image file that you are sending to the JSON Request body.

You can refere to this post here:

[Javascript: Upload File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5587973/javascript-upload-file)

Comment: Even if I change the Axios to fetch and do it as you say... `    fetch(`${HOST}/books/${books_id}/upload`, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
  
        Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`
      },
      body: data
    })` ... still does the exact same thing.. File gets transported but its size 0 as if there is no content coming with it

Comment: Try logging the file on the backend and let us know what it prints.

Comment: that's what file prints on backend `{
  fieldname: 'file',
  originalname: 'nineteen-eighty-four.jpg',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
  buffer: <Buffer ff d8 ff e0 00 10 4a 46 49 46 00 01 01 00 00 01 00 01 00 00 ff db 00 43 00 0b 08 08 08 08 08 0b 08 08 0b 10 0b 09 0b 10 13 0e 0b 0b 0e 13 16 12 12 13 ... 284783 more bytes>,
  size: 284833
}
` I'm guessing it's missing stuff like temporary path and stream but i have no idea why..