# Is it possible to allow a user to upload a video to their channel through a HTML/javascript form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-api, youtube, youtube-api

Is it possible to allow a user to upload a video to their channel through a HTML/javascript form?
If yes I am not sure how the google authentication would work on users end.
The code snippets refer to using one's own account (e.g. api key and secret key), so they are not helpful in my case.

Comment: Does this answer your question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5587973/javascript-upload-file/51109645

Edit:
I've assumed it's uploading files to your project…
 Or are you talking about uploading video to youtube or other existing service?

Comment: Yeah, I am talking about uploading video to youtube.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask 

Maybe edit your question a bit. as it really isn't clear

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, but you need a backend/server-side code too and wrap up your form as an app and the user needs to allow the app to be able to upload the video through your app on Youtube.