# how to get a temp file from $_GET in php

Tags: php, ajax, file-upload, temporary-files

I want to return a temp file name from php using ajax but the code i have tried so far doesn't working. Here is the code:-

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
      <head>
    <script>
    function getValue(){
        var file=document.getElementById("file").value;
        var xhr;
        if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
            xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        url="getImageValue.php?data="+file;
        xhr.open("GET",url,false);
        xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
            if(xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200){
                document.getElementById("feedback").innerHTML=xhr.responseText;
            }
        }
        xhr.send(null);
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

       <input type="file" id="file" name="file" />
       <input type="button" id="submit" name="submit" value="catch" onClick="getValue()" />

      <div id="feedback"></div>
    </body>
   </html>
```

**getImageValue.php**

```
<?php
     echo basename($_GET["data"]);
?>
```

Please help.. Jason

Comment: code is working check url="getImageValue.php?data="+file; have you correct path of file

Comment: Your coding working well for just show upload image name but it doesn't upload image to server.

Comment: Yup code is working and its returning the name of file but what i want is that it must return a tmp file name like a $_FILES["name of file"]["tmp_name"] returns.

Comment: @Manibharathi I know it doesnt uploading to the server coz i haven't got any temp_name from a file.

Answer (score 1):

Use form tag with `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute.

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/upload/image" method="post">
```

[Ajax using file upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/502375/ajax-using-file-upload)

[jQuery Ajax File Upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload)