# Limit on FileReference uploads?

Tags: actionscript-3, upload, filereference

I am currently uploading files in ActionScript 3 using the upload() method of the FileReference class.

I built an uploader than can do simultaneous or parallel uploads, having a variable set the number of maximum uploads at a time.

I noticed that for Internet Explorer I could be uploading 10 or more files simultaneously, but FireFox and Safari seems to cap the number of uploads to 2. That is, when I call the upload method on per say, 3 files, only 2 will get events back (such as ProgressEvent.PROGRESS). Only when one of the 2 uploads finishes, then the 3rd one will start. This behavior does not happen for Internet Explorer. I have tried with a large number of files, and some big files, to make sure this behavior was consistent.

I was wondering if anyone noticed this behavior please, and if so, what is the reason for this behavior please?

I appreciate your help,

Thank you very much,

Rudy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a limited number of simultaneous connections to each host, which varies from browser to browser. This limit is generally discussed in the context of downloading many things (e.g. images) simultaneously *from* the server, but it seems to apply to uploads as well (this makes sense because connections are two-way).

Check out [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2195462/uploading-multiple-files-simultaneously-with-flex), especially [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2195462/uploading-multiple-files-simultaneously-with-flex/2198962#2198962) that expands on what I've said here. It links to some useful articles.