# ActiveX control for drag and drop file upload in IE

Tags: asp.net, file, upload, drag-and-drop

Hi
I need a drag and drop file upload in my asp.net application like gmail but it should support IE browser only.I thing i have to develop a ActiveX control to achieve this .Can any one guide me or give me a link how to develop this.

Regards
Vairam

Answer (score 0):

This post is pretty old, but if you're still interested, there's a pretty comprehensive article here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301932.aspx

Extended here for multiple files via drag and drop:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aoakley/archive/2004/02/16/74460.aspx

Comment: the proposed solution in these articles is client-wide installation of the 20MB .NET runtime

Answer (score 0):

ActiveX = AHHHHHH!!!

But in all seriousness, could you use a [GMail upload "clone"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135123/how-can-i-get-gmail-like-file-uploads-for-my-web-app) and simply restrict it so that it only works in IE